# Java: How to return document’s that were deleted by solr

Tags: java, database, apache, solr, delete-operator

Is there a way to return all of the documents that were deleted when a deletebyquery is conducted by the solr client in java? Or atleast the id’s of the documents that were deleted?

Comment: I doubt you can return them, but if you want some info about the files, then try looking at the Logging page, it may contain the info you need: http://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_4/logging.html